# In Perl, why is the order of `values %hash` different than the order in the list I used to create %hash?

Tags: perl

I am extracting an array from a hash, and I have printed the array but can see the order of output is different. Why is this?

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

%data = ('John Paul' => 45, 'Lisa' => 30, 'Kumar' => 40);

@ages = values %data;

print "$ages[0]\n";
print "$ages[1]\n";
print "$ages[2]\n";
```

Comment: @serenesat No, hashes do not have order until you impose an external order relation on them. Arrays have order because their keys are integers which have a natural order defined on them without regard to how they are used. Even then, the natural order of an array may not be the order you want to impose on the data structure which is why there is a `sort` function.

Comment: Yeah ..got it. deleting my comment.

Answer (score 4):

Hash tables do not have order. If you want the values out in a specific order, you can either iterate through keys in that order:

```
for my $person (('John Paul', 'Kumar', 'Lisa')) {
    my $age = $data{ $person };
    ...
```

Or, use a hash slice with the desired key order:

```
@ages = @data{ ('John Paul', 'Kumar', 'Lisa') };
```

See also [How can I make my hash remember the order I put elements into it?](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfaq4#How-can-I-make-my-hash-remember-the-order-I-put-elements-into-it) in the FAQ list.

You should read the FAQ list at least a few times.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use something like [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::IxHash) which looks like a hash but isn't actually (which means it doesn't have the same performance characteristics of a hash), the order in which you get the elements is going to be unpredicatable<sup>[1]</sup>. As such, it's a common practice to control the order in which the hash elements are visited through some external means such as `sort`.

```
for my $key (sort keys(%hash)) {
   ...
}
```

---

A hash is an array of linked lists. A hashing function converts the key into a number which is used as the index of the array element ("bucket") into which to store the value. The linked list handles the case where more than one key hashes to the same index ("collision").

So the elements are naturally ordered by index, which is to say by the hash of their key. To the casual observer, this order would appear to be random.

---

But Perl makes changes to this natural order for security reasons.

When a bucket starts receiving a large percentage of the elements of a hash, the performance of the hash degrades since a lookup becomes a search of a linked list. A malicious actor could DOS a system by deliberately feeding values that would trigger the degenerate case.

Perl takes steps to avoid the scenario and to fix the hash when it becomes degenerate by accident or through ill intent. I'm not familiar with all the details, and they have changed over the year. They involve randomizing the hashing algorithm and randomizing the order in which elements are returned.

This makes the order appear even more random,

---

1. One exception: The order in which `keys`, `value` and `each` return elements is always the same for a given hash as long as you don't change the hash.

   ```
   $ perl -E'
      @h{ "a".."i" } = 0..8;
      say map { $h{$_} } keys %h;
      say map { $h{$_} } keys %h;
      say values %h;

      $h{j} = 9;
      say map { $h{$_} } keys %h;
      say map { $h{$_} } keys %h;
      say values %h;
   '
   580734216
   580734216
   580734216
   0985216734
   0985216734
   0985216734
   ```

   The means it's safe to do the following:

   ```
   # Add the elements of %hash1 to %hash2.
   @hash2{ keys(%hash1) } = values(%hash1);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html):

> Hash entries are returned in an apparently random order. The actual random order is specific to a given hash; the exact same series of operations on two hashes may result in a different order for each hash. Any insertion into the hash may change the order, as will any deletion, with the exception that the most recent key returned by each or keys may be deleted without changing the order. So long as a given hash is unmodified you may rely on keys, values and each to repeatedly return the same order as each other. See [Algorithmic Complexity Attacks in perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks) for details on why hash order is randomized.